# What is best way to resolve merge conflict with protected master branch case?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, rebase

In my team, we have production Gitlab with protected master branch to which I can only merge request from the browser. I accept MR myself.

What's the problem:
The master branch has hash F, the feature branch has hash U. They both have a merge base with hash A. That is, both master and feature have had a lot of changes. I need to completely replace the code in master with the code from feature, while doing this without using the method of deleting the feature branch.The problem is compounded by the fact that I can only git push to a feature, and only do MR from the GUI.

I tried to

```
git checkout master
git commit-tree -p master -p feature -m "Overriding master with feature" feature^{tree}
git merge --ff 12346aa23590aa
```

But it does merge in local master which i can't send to remote

Comment: Sounds like the GUI is not up to par to your task. You can always do the merge locally in the way you need, then make a merge request from the result. That should out-smart the inferior capabilities of the GUI.

Comment: Your commit-tree process is good, but since you can't push directly on ref `master`, you have to create a temp branch, call it `into-master` or something, branched off `master`, and do your commit-tree commit on it. Then push and make a MR from `into-master` to `master`.

Comment: Where is the merge conflict that you mention in the title? I don't see it anywhere in the body of the question.

Comment: Locally, merge master into feature with `-s ours`. You now have a merge commit that is identical to feature but the merge base is moved all the way up to the tip of main. Now make a merge request and merge feature into main. Since main makes no contribution since the merge base, the result will look like feature.